# Openlayers OSM always set on (long/lat) (0/0)

Tags: javascript, openlayers, openstreetmap

this is my code

```
map = new OpenLayers.Map("map");    
// I tried several projections here, all lead to the same result
var proj = new OpenLayers.Projection("WGS84");
var point = new OpenLayers.LonLat(position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude);
point.transform(proj, map.getProjectionObject());
    
// the output of this shows the correct coordinates
console.log("latitude: "+position.coords.latitude+"  long "+position.coords.longitude);
    
var mapnik = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM();
map.addLayer(mapnik);
map.setCenter(point,3);
```

It always shows the map centered on coordinate (0/0) which is somewhere in the Atlantic Ocean. Where is my error? I cant solve this and find nothing on Google.

This, however, works.

```
map = new OpenLayers.Map( 'map');
layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM( "Simple OSM Map");
map.addLayer(layer);
map.setCenter(
  new OpenLayers.LonLat(position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude).transform(
  new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
  map.getProjectionObject()
  ), 12
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you tried several projections and all lead to the same result that's probably because Proj4js is not correctly loaded (see http://trac.osgeo.org/openlayers/wiki/Documentation/Dev/proj4js)

Check also this example: http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/osm.html (coords re-projection from EPSG:4326)

Comment: the second example is working, see my post. But why? To me, it does basically the same.

Comment: maybe the `WGS84` vs `EPSG:4326` ?

Comment: hmm, yes thats it. I thought I have tryed it before too...well thanks a lot anyway!